# C# - Making text appear letter by letter in a label?

Tags: c#, class, label

I'm super new to coding and still pretty bad at it, but sadly I haven't been able to find anything that could help me.

I wanted to have a little dialog label for this game that we're making for children, the letters appear one by one in a label and then after pressing a button you get the next piece of dialog. So far I have this SlowWriter class:

```
public class SlowWriter
    {

        public static void Write(string text)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                Console.Write(c);
                Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(30, 60));
            }
        }
    }
```

But I really cannot figure out how to display this method in a label? 'Cause I have this in my button click event

```
SlowWriter.Write("Lorem Ipsum");
```

but this will just display it in the output thingy and not the label? And I can't just simply convert it to a string and display that in the label.

Comment: What kid of label? Is this winforms? WPF? ...?

Comment: 'output thingy' is console in your case, since you are printing to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use WinForms you can create a SlowLabel Control that you can put on your form and use like any other form. It uses a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) that knows how to handle UI cross-thread operations. And for the characters to process it uses an [`IEnumerator<char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) that exists on the string.

```
public class SlowLabel:Label
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(); // Ticks now and then

    IEnumerator<char> text = null; // holds the characters that still need to show up

    static Random r = new Random(); // guarantee randomness

    public SlowLabel()
    {
        timer.Interval = r.Next(30,60);       // when is the next tick
        timer.Enabled = false;                // let's not start now
        timer.Tick += (s,e) => {              // do one character
            base.Text += text.Current;        // Current has charactwer to Add
            timer.Interval = r.Next(30,60);   // random next run 
            timer.Enabled = text.MoveNext();  // or we stop if no more charcters
        };
    }

    public override string Text 
    {
       set
       {
          text = value.GetEnumerator();       // get the charcters to process
          base.Text = String.Empty;           // start empty
          timer.Enabled = text.MoveNext();    // tell the timer to start 
       }
    }
}
```

When you have dropped it on your form you can use it like so:

```
private void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    l1.Text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    l2.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
}
```

Which will give you this result:

[image: slow label with characters appearing]

Answer (score 0):

The Console.Write(c) is sending the characters to the Console, rather than a label.

In your Write function, you can add a parameter for the label you want to write to, and use a StringBuilder to append characters.

You want this Write function to run asynchronously, so your thread isn't tied up until the whole string is written, so we'll create a Task and run it. In this case, you'll need to use Invoke to call the UI thread to change the label's text.

This solution is for WinForms, but the general idea is there.

```
public class SlowWriter
{
    public static void Write(string text, Label lbl)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                sb.Append(c);
                if (lbl.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    lbl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lbl.Text = sb.ToString(); });
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl.Text = sb.ToString();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(30, 60));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this, the only change to the button click event is passing in the label you want to write to, so it will look something like this, where "lbl" is the variable name of the desired label object.

```
SlowWriter.Write("Lorem Ipsum", lbl);
```